# Get index of element in container if element exists

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I am improving my C++ skills by learning to use better the algorithms in the standard library. I have an issue that I am not sure how to solve correctly using algorirhtms. I need to check if an element exists in a vector and if it exists, get its index.

With a raw loop I would use an integer and increment it for each iteration.

With algorithms I have only been able to use `std::find` and then use `std::distance`, but this requires more computations than a raw loop. What would be the best way to do this task using algorithms?

Comment: *but this requires more computations than a raw loop* -- Where did you get this information?

Comment: it looks pretty clear to me that it would do more things. First I iterate and then I compute the distance...

Comment: ok, let's see the *complete* setup of finding an element using a loop.  Remember that the index must be available *outside* the loop body, so "tricks" such as `for (int i..)` will not work since `i` must be available outside the loop.

Comment: I have test it and maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it appears a raw loop is less expensive https://godbolt.org/z/HwBHDL

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, since `i` is not initialized.  The next issue is that you should move your hand-written code in a function, and see what happens.  You are basically comparing a generic function that, when given the correct arguments, **always** works, and the human making sure that all of their hand-coded loops has no bugs (size wrong, for example).

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the best way to do this task using algorithms?

Use `std::find` and then use `std::distance`.

Except for containers which have a more efficient `find` member function such as associative containers. In that case, use `find` member function and `std::distance`.

There are also data structures with more efficient ways to calculate the distance than can be achieved through iterators, but no standard container use such data structure.

> but this requires more computations than a raw loop.

It does not (assuming an optimising compiler).

> why not?

Because the standard algorithms in question don't need to do anything that the raw loop doesn't do.

Comment: why not? at least it requires the computation of the distance. an optimising compiler would optimize to a single substraction assuming a vector, but still is something. it would also be a problem with other containers, no?

Comment: well, im using two standard algorithms. with a raw loop I could combine both operations, find and distance, in one single loop, no? https://godbolt.org/z/HwBHDL

Comment: @jjcasmar You cannot use indexed loops with containers in general, because not all containers have random access. In theory, the compiler is allowed to optimise the subtraction away by using the same trick that you did, but it hardly ever matters because a single subtraction is in most cases unmeasurably fast because there is probably something else that is a bottleneck.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking. Is still more operations, but still doesnt matter. Just wanted to know if there was any other way. I guess clarity here is more important and using two algorithms is cleaner. Regarding your last edit about the `find` member function. Shouldn't std::find be specialized for that particular container to call the member function? Do std containers specialize?

Comment: @jjcasmar Bottom line: More operations for abstract machine does not matter when optimiser optimises the operations away.

Comment: @jjcasmar `std::find` cannot be specialised for that because it operates on iterators. It is clear how specialisation of `std::distance` works for random access iterators, but there is no concept of "lookup" iterator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211037/discussion-between-jjcasmar-and-eerorika).